# mostrar / imprimir arbol en un JtextField o caja de texto JAVA

Tags: java

cordial saludo,

necesito que por favor alguien me ayude a imprimir o mostrar los datos de un arbol echo en java en un jtextfield,

la impresion en cada uno de sus recorridos (inorden, preorden, postOrden) por consola imprimi normal, pero a la hora de montarlo en modo interfaz y querer mostrarlo en un jtextield arroja demasiados errrores, necesito de su colaboracion para poder terminar este pequeño software,

el codigo es el siguiente

el del recorrido InOrden

```
public void inorden(Arbol raiz)
    {

    if(raiz==null)
        {
        return;
        }
    else
        {
            inorden(raiz.izq);
            System.out.println(raiz.letra);
            inorden(raiz.der);
         }
    }
```

hasta aca todo bien el imprime normal por consola el arbol, pero la idea es imprimirlo o mostrarlo por modo interfaz , creo q en un jtextield deberia aparecer, pero no he tenido exito,

```
private void btn_inordenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    // TODO add your handling code here:



    inorden(raiz); // aca llamo el metodo recursivo

    panelImpresion.setVisible(true); // muestro el panel donde se encuentra en jtextField llamado txt_impresion

    txt_impresion.setText(raiz); // solo muestra la raiz,



}
```

tambien he intentado almacenar inorden(raiz) en un String para concatenarlo y luego llamarlo en el txt_impresion, pero tampoco, existe alguna manera de mostrarlo asi como lo estoy tratando o solo es por consola???? por favor ayuda....

dejo una imagen del programita, cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, de antemano muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Reemplaza la linea del código

```
System.out.println(raiz.letra);
```

Por

```
txt_impresion.setText(txt_impresion.getText() + "-->" + raiz.letra);
```